# static int initialization

Tags: c++, static

how to correct it so I can display the static int by

```
cout<<A::a<<endl;
```

like in an example below?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
    public:
        static int a = 0;
};

int main()
{
    cout << A::a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside the class definition, the static members are only *declared* and not defined. By default, only *definitions* have initialization, with the exception that for static constants of integral types the *declaration* can have the initialization.

The problem in your program is that the static member is used (`std::cout << A::a` is *odr-use* for non-const static member attributes), but you have no definition. You need to define the variable in a single translation unit in your program by adding:

```
int A::a = value;
```

(Note that because the static member is *not* const, you cannot provide an initializer inside the class definition, so you need to remove the `= 0` from the declaration in class definition. Also note that you can skip the `= value` in the initialization if `value == 0`, as static initialization will set `A::a` to 0 before any other initialization)

Comment: +1 in this particular case making it const & initializing it inside the class would work.

Answer (score 5):

Either:

```
class A{
    public:
        static const int a = 0;
};
```

(const integral types can be initialized inside the class definition)

or

```
class A{
    public:
        static int a;
};

int A::a = 0;
```

Comment: In the second example, why I have to redeclare 'a' as an int?

Comment: @RobertKilar previously you just declared it, now you're defining it. That's just the syntax.

Comment: but type NAME ... is declaration

Comment: @RobertKilar and definition. You can have as many declarations as you want, you can't have multiple definitions and you can't define something without specifying the type.

Comment: Note that for a static constant member you might still need to provide a definition (without initialization if the initialization is present in the declaration) if it is *odr-used* (you create a pointer or reference to the static member attribute)

Comment: @RobertKilar: `type name;` is a **definition**. A definition of a variable at namespace/function level is also a *declaration* if it does not have the `extern` keyword. For a static member attribute, `type enclosingtype::name;` is a *definition* but not a *declaration*, the *declaration* is inside the class *definition* (confused enough now?)